# How to change separator kartik\tree\TreeViewInput?

Tags: php, yii2

When selecting a value from TreeViewInput::widget, if there is a comma in the value, the input is displayed as if it were multiple values, how can I fix this?

```
TreeViewInput::widget([
                        'model' => $model,
                        'attribute' => 'stringMktus',
                        'value' => 'value1|value2|value3', // preselected values
                        'query' => MktuTree::getQueryForMktuTree(),
                        'headingOptions' => ['label' => 'Классы МКТУ'],
                        'rootOptions' => ['label'=>'<i class="fas fa-tree text-success"></i>'],
                        'dropdownConfig' => [
                            'input' => [
                                'placeholder' => 'Выберите класс МКТУ...',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'fontAwesome' => true,
                        'asDropdown' => true,
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'options' => ['disabled' => false],
                    ]);
```

[image]

I tried searching the documentation, but didn't really find anything.

Comment: It looks like the separator cannot be changed. You can try to encode commas in values as `&comma;` before using it in tree view input. But, it might end up being encoded.